# Pythonic slicing of nested attributes

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iterator, slice

I am dealing with classes whose attributes are sometimes list whose elements can be dictionaries or further nested objects with attributes etc. I would like to perform some slicing that with my grasp of python is only doable with what feels profoundly un-Pythonic.

My minimal code looks like this:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.a = []

x=X()
x.a.append({'key1':'v1'})
x.a.append({'key1':'v2'})
x.a.append({'key1':'v3'})

# this works as desired
x.a[0]['key1'] # 'v1'
```

I would like to perform an access to a key in the nested dictionary but make that call for all elements of the list containing that dictionary. The standard python way of doing this would be a list comprehension a la:

```
[v['key1'] for v in x.a]
```

However, my minimal example doesn't quite convey the full extent of nesting in my real-world scenario: The attribute list `a` in class `X` might contain objects, whose attributes are objects, whose attributes are dictionaries whose keys I want to select on while iterating over the outer list.

```
# I would like something like
useful_list = x.a[:]['key1'] # TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
# or even better
cool_list = where(x.a[:]['key1'] == 'v2') # same TypeError
```

If I start list comprehending for every interesting key it quickly doesn't look all that Pythonic. Is there a nice way of doing this or do I have to code 'getter' methods for all conceivable pairings of lists and dictionary keys?

UPDATE:
I have been reading about overloading lists. Apparently one can mess with the **getitem** method which is used for indeces for lists and keys for dict. Maybe a custom class that iterates over list members. This is starting to sound contrived...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to create an hierarchical structure, with an operation which means
different things for different types, and is defined recursively.
Polymorphism to the rescue.

You could override `__getitem__` instead of my `get_items` below, but in your case it might be better to define a non-builtin operation to avoid risking ambiguity.  It's up to you really.

```
class ItemsInterface(object):
    def get_items(self, key):
        raise NotImplementedError

class DictItems(ItemsInterface, dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def get_items(self, key):
        res = self[key]
        # apply recursively
        try:
            res = res.get_items(key)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return res

class ListItems(ItemsInterface, list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        list.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def get_items(self, key):
        return [ x.get_items(key) for x in self ]

x = ListItems()
x.append(DictItems({'key1':'v1'}))
x.append(DictItems({'key1':'v2'}))
x.append(DictItems({'key1':'v3'}))
y = DictItems({'key1':'v999'})
x.append(ListItems([ y ]))
x.get_items('key1')
=> ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', ['v999']]
```

Of course, this solution might not be exactly what you need (you didn't explain what it should do if the key is missing, etc.)
but you can easily modify it to suit your needs.

This solution also supports `ListItems` as values of the `DictItems`.  the `get_items` operation is applied recursively.

Comment: That works exactly as desired. Thanks. It also has a safer feel to it due to making the changes explicit (access through a new method rather than redefining what x['key1'] does). Nice